# How to get size of spine game object in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I’m trying to get the display width and height of a spine game object created with this code:

```
let boy = this.add.spine(0, 0, 'boy', 'standing', true);
```

When I print out, boy.x and boy.y are valid. But boy.width and boy.height (or boy.displayWidth and boy.displayHeight) are undefined. I'm a bit lost here...
Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem by looking at the spine plugin source code.
It doesn't have width, height properties. Instead it has a getBounds() function.
But getBounds() return actual size of the texture, so I have to multiply the size with scale value:

```
let boyWidth = boy.getBounds().size.x * boy.scaleX;
```

Little note here is: size.x, not size.width. Because that's how the spine plugin was written.
Hope this is useful for someone.